# Linking error when calling a function

Tags: linker-errors, lnk2019

When my code is calling a certain function, I'm getting an error:

> H:\workspace\HW5\HW5\Manager.obj
>
> Error 22 error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void
> __thiscall Shalishut::Task8_MoveVehicleFromBaseToBase(class
> Military *,char const *,char *,char
> *)" (?Task8_MoveVehicleFromBaseToBase@Shalishut@@QAEXPAVMilitary@@PBDPAD2@Z)
> referenced in function "public: void
> __thiscall Manager::TaskExecute(class Task *,class Military *,class
> Shalishut *,char * * const)"
> (?TaskExecute@Manager@@QAEXPAVTask@@PAVMilitary@@PAVShalishut@@QAPAD@Z)
> H:\workspace\HW5\HW5\Manager.objH:\workspace\HW5\HW5\Manager.obj

and:

> error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals H:\workspace\HW5\Debug\HW5.exe

When I'm not calling that function, everything is OK and the project builds.

Here is the code calling the function:

```
shalishut->Task8_MoveVehicleFromBaseToBase(military,licenseId,campNameA,campNameB);
```

and here is the function:

```
void Task8_MoveVehicleFromBaseToBase(Military* military,const char* licenseId,char* fromBase,char* toBase){
 if (military->IsBaseExist(fromBase)){
  if(military->FindBase(fromBase)->IsVehicleExist(licenseId)){
   if (military->IsBaseExist(toBase)){
    if(military->GetCountry()->IsRoadExist(military->FindBase(fromBase)->GetCityName(),military->FindBase(toBase)->GetCityName())){
     military->FindBase(toBase)->AddVehicleToBase( military->FindBase(fromBase)->RemoveVehicleFromBase(licenseId) );
     Time* time = Time::GetInstance();
     long double distance = military->GetCountry()->GetRoadDistance(military->FindBase(fromBase)->GetCityName(),military->FindBase(toBase)->GetCityName());
     Transport* transportToAdd = new Transport(time->GetTime(),(string)fromBase,(string)toBase,distance);
     military->FindVehicle(licenseId)->AddTransport(transportToAdd);
    }
   }
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: More data is definetly needed. Start with the language / compiler

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the function declaration needs to be:

```
void Shalishut::Task8_MoveVehicleFromBaseToBase(Military* military,const char* licenseId,char* fromBase,char* toBase) {
...
}
```

You didn't really provide us with header files so I'm assuming that function is a member of the shalishut class.